# How to selecting text outisude div with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup, gettext

Here's my problem, i have HTML code like this.

```
<div class="article">
     "Some text over here"
      <div class="ads">
            "ads text over here"
      </div>
<div>
```

What i'm trying to do is, i want to get text from div class="artikel".

For now, i already try this jsoup code.

```
doc.select("div[class=article]").text();
```

But what i got from that code is

> "Some text over here ads text over here"

What i really want is only get

> "Some text over here"

Is there anyone can help me to get that text with only use jsoup's CSS selector ?

I don't want to use any string library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ownText()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29) to exclude all the containing tag elements of the selected element :

```
doc.select("div.article").first().ownText();
```

Also , depending on your requirement , you may be interested in the [textNodes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes%28%29) too :

```
For example, with the input HTML: 
<p>One <span>Two</span> Three <br> Four</p> with the p element selected:

p.text() = "One Two Three Four"
p.ownText() = "One Three Four"
p.children() = Elements[<span>, <br>]
p.childNodes() = List<Node>["One ", <span>, " Three ", <br>, " Four"]
p.textNodes() = List<TextNode>["One ", " Three ", " Four"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like 
doc.select("div.article").text().substring(0, 22);

Comment: Deven, thanks for your answer. But i only want to use CSS selector to get the text.

Comment: If you are going to select the text of class"article" so it will display all text that are there inside class"article",so may be i m wrong but i guess that it is not possible to get only 'Some text over here'  using  doc.select("div[class=article]").text(); you will have to use doc.select("div[class=article]").text().substring(0, 22); for that...Please update my comment if you find a good way to do that ..Thanks